# Monitor docker containers based on labels assigned

Tags: docker, mesos, mesosphere, bosun, cadvisor

I am using bosun+cadvisor to monitor docker containers across my mesos infrastructure.
Is there any way to monitor specific docker container or containers and write an alert?

Maybe using the label assigned to the containers? Because I cannot use the container name (mesos generates a custom name for the container).

Thanks.

EDIT:
I found that cadvisor supports docker labels. Anyway to get the to scollector and to bosun to query using labels?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the TagOverride feature in scollector to generate additional tags for the cadvisor metrics. I'm not sure what the docker_name format looks like for mesos, but for Kubernetes you would use:

```
[[Cadvisor]]
  URL = "http://mydockerhost01:8080"

#Override tags for Kubernetes containers
[[TagOverride]]
  CollectorExpr = "cadvisor"
  [TagOverride.MatchedTags]
    docker_name = 'k8s_(?P<container_name>[^\.]+)\.[0-9a-z]+_(?P<pod_name>[^-]+)'
    docker_id = '^(?P<docker_id>.{12})'
  [TagOverride.Tags]
    docker_name = ''
    name = ''
```

This would override the docker_id tags (shorten to 12 chars), add a container_name and pod_name tag, and remove the docker_name and name tag.